# Elasticsearch on DynamoDB List of Maps

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb

I have this following DynamoDB field added to Elastic Search.

Index : MYINDEX

Type : MYTYPE

Mapping of MYTPE is shown below:

```
'roadmapParams': {
    'properties': {'L': {
         'properties': {'M': {
             'properties': {'project_id': {
               'properties': {'S': {
                  'fields': {
                    'keyword': {'ignore_above': 256,'type': 'keyword'}
                   },
                  'type': 'text'}}
              }, 
         }}}}}}
```

To search on the `project_id` field I did the below query to the this url:
`https://my_domain.com/MYINDEX/MYTYPE`

```
"query": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "roadmapParams",
                "query": {
                    "regexp": {
                        "roadmapParams.L.M.project_id.S": partial_match
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Is this the way to query list of maps in DDB ?

Comment: what's the URL you're sending this request to? Not the hostname, just the path.

Comment: BTW if `roadmapParams` itself is not mapped as type `nested`, the query isnt going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this for ES 6.0 and upwards.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

# use aws4auth to make auth
# host is without https://

es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
                       http_auth=auth,
                       use_ssl=True,
                       verify_certs=True,
                       connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection)

s = Search.from_dict({
        "query": {
            "regexp": {
                "roadmapParams.L.M.project_id.S": partial_match
            }
        },
    }).index('MYINDEX').using(es)

response = s.execute()
```